# How to insert specific lines into a file using vim?

Tags: vim, vi, clipboard

I am using `vim` for both programming and competitive coding.

Now, since I want to insert specific macros whenever I open a source file when I am doing competitive coding. I just copy paste the entire macros into the `vim` editor manually from the place where I saved them.

Is there any way I can do this more efficiently in `vim` editor, like say I press <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>and the macros get inserted at the top of the source file automatically ?

If yes, then what changes do I need into the `.vimrc` file to do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various solutions to this explained in an existing post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690386/writing-a-vim-function-to-insert-a-block-of-static-text

Answer (score 1):

If you mean inserting boilerplate code or reusable code fragments, you can define mappings, insert mode abbreviations, or use one of the more powerful *snippets* plugins.

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are also plugins that automatically populate an empty file with a template.

---

*Macros* usually mean keystrokes / command sequences recorded in a register, or mappings derived from that. If you want them only for your competitive coding sessions, you can put those into a separate `macros.vim` script, and `:source` that on demand (vs. putting them directly into `~/.vimrc`). Even sourcing can be automated:

#### Local config with built-in functionality

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory.

#### Local config through plugin

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.